# su postgres in Mac OS does not work

Tags: postgresql, macos

I'am trying:

```
su postgres
```

Enter password of root, but receive: Sorry
I tried this:

```
sudo -u postgres
```

But receive:
    could not identify current directory: Permission denied

When I try

```
 sudo su postgres
```

receive:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
```

In pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

Comment: Where are you running those commands? In root's home directory /root or in a user's home directory such as /home/user? Also, why do you need to `su` to postgres if the Postgresql service is already running?

Comment: `sudo -i` type in your own password, and then `su - postgres` . Does this give you the same error?

Comment: use `su - postgres`

Answer (score 1):

- `su postgres`

Requires the password for the user `postgres`, not `root`

- `sudo -u postgres`

`Permission denied`

Found a workaround at https://trac.macports.org/ticket/18024

`cd /tmp ; sudo -u postgres` ...

So, the user `postgres` doesn't have permissions in the CWD where you ran the `sudo` command from.

- `pg_hba.conf`

Has nothing to do with the `su`/`sudo`, it is for db connectivity from psql or a db client.